# Using an array return from a function

Tags: c#, arrays

In a function I am taking an array and resizing it.  I made the function an array return type and it does what it is supposed to do.  The problem I am having is figuring out how to use the returned array in my program.  hiLow is a function that takes the array and changes the value, the for loop only still shows the old array.  How do I get creature(the name of my array) to only display the new values?

```
        hiLow(creature);
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(creature[i].creatureInfo());
        }
```

Comment: Please post the code for hiLow

Comment: Elaborate your question with some additional example code. What do you mean "*how to use the returned array in my program?*" is certainly uncleared. Looking like a **homeworky** question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return crature from your method.

```
creature = hiLow(creature);
```

Comment: Thanks it turned out to be something very different, but the error that popped up after I put the code in helped me figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing exactly what is going on without seeing your code, one thing you will want to do is pass the array by reference into your `hiLow` method.  This will modify the array that is being passed in and you should be able to see the new size of your array in the loop.

```
 hiLow(ref creature);
 for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(creature[i].creatureInfo());
 }
```